# Cant format the json body for moving a file in Graph Api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a file that i want to move to a different folder in one drive and am trying to format the body as follows:

```
        var body = new
        {

            parentReference = 
            { 
                id= folderId;
            },
            name = fileId;
        };
```

I am getting an error , saying name does not exist , id does not exist .
How can i fomat the body for a request in c# ?

Comment: You need to remove semicolon `;` from after `folderId` and `fileId` .

Comment: `var body = new { parentReference = new { id= folderId}, name = fileId};`